Visibility viewports\renders togglable option for specific collection of animations
I have a set of POV hand animations (4, to be precise). One animation is called unsheathe, wich is basic unsheathing animation. I also have Sword object with sword armature (a single bone). So i've researched internet to find a way, to make sword object disappear. Many tutorials called for Visibility property in Object Properties, wich is working (e.g. i need for the sword to be invisible from frame 0 to frame 7, so i untoggled show in for viewport and render at 0 and toggled it back on 7). But it also changes visibility of the sword in all other collections, so i have my sword reappear on frame 7 in any other animation. I've tried applaying it with In active Group or Only Selected Channels (when pressing I on Action editor) and it's still the same conclusion. Sword is disappearing and appearing in all of my animations. Is there a way to fix it?


Put the sword into it's own collection, then instance in the same way I explain in this answer. Then instead of having the sword object referenced in multiple collections you can just have several separate instanced sword objects and animate the viewport visibility of the modifier where you want to hide it instead. I think that should solve your problem.
